# Java: draw line on JPanel inside JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();

f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();
JPanel p1,p2;

p1=new JPanel();
p2=new JPanel();


p1.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
p2.setBounds(0,0,200,200);

p1.setOpaque(false);
p2.setOpaque(false);

layers.setLayer(p1,new Integer(0));
layers.setLayer(p2,new Integer(1));

layers.add(p1);
layers.add(p2);

f.add(layers);
f.setVisible(true);


Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) p2.getGraphics();
gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);

gr.drawLine(10,10,20,20);
```

I am trying to draw on a JPanel inside a JLayeredPane, but nothing is drawn. If I add a component (a JButton) to either p1 or p2, it will be painted.

What is the correct way to draw inside a JLayeredPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just draw to the graphics context externally, it is not persistent like you'd might expect.  Instead you need to override JComponent.paintComponent(Graphics g) in the JPanel. Try this. Ideally you'd subclass JPanel as a separate class.

A good oracle tutorial is "[Perform custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)"

```
p2=new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) g;
        gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        gr.drawLine(10,10,20,20)

    }

}
```

Comment: But what if I want to draw lines dynamically? The only option is to add an array of "lines" in the JPanel class and to invoke repaint()?

Comment: Yes, exactly, your paintComponent can reference some state (list, model etc) that you control elsewhere, then call repaint()...